# c# linq to xml update all descendants of specific value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xattribute

I am creating a configuration file editor, and am currently implementing features for updating existing data.  I would like to be able to update all attributes within the file which have a specific attribute, such as updating a user name.

My XML file represents users in the following manner:

```
<user user="user1" ... />
<user user="user2" ... />
```

My present attempt looks like this:

```
 xdoc.Descendants().Where(a => a.Attribute("user").Value == UserEditInput).FirstOrDefault().SetAttributeValue("user", NewUser);
```

where `UserEditInput` is the name of the current user name and `NewUser` is the new replacement value.

This throws a `NullReferenceException`.  There are a number of "user" XAttributes in the form shown above with a value equal to that of `UserEditInput`.  This leads me to believe I am not referencing the desired data in the correct manner, not modifying the attributes correctly, or both.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're trying to fetch the value for the `user` attribute of *every* element in the document - including the root element, for example.

Two options here, which I'd probably use both of:

- Specify that you only want `user` elements, using `xdoc.Descendants("user")`
- Use a cast of `XAttribute` to `string` instead of the `Value` property; that way if there's no such attribute, the cast will return `null` as well

Additionally, if you don't find the matching element, you're using `FirstOrDefault` so you'll get a value of null - but you try to set the attribute value anyway. Don't do that.

So, putting it all together - and taking a short cut by using the overload of `FirstOrDefault` with a predicate:

```
var element = xdoc.Descendants("user")
                  .FirstOrDefault(a => (string) a.Attribute("user") == UserEditInput);

if (element != null)
{
    element.SetAttributeValue("user", NewUser);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  The above code works well for editing the user names within a specific section.  How would I adapt the code to amend all attributes with the value of UserEditInput throughout the file?  Using my previous (and only) idea of xdoc.Descendants() doesn't work.

Comment: You can get a list of `element`s (`Where(a => (string) a.Attribute("user") == UserEditInput)`) instead get only the first (`FirstOrDefault(a => (string) a.Attribute("user") == UserEditInput)`) and iterate in it, updating each element with `SetAttributeValue` method ( `foreach(var element in query){ element.SetAttributeValue("user", NewUser);}`)

Comment: @TimB: You'd use a `foreach` loop, basically. But that's a different question, and should be asked in a different post, after research and trying things.

Comment: I have accepted the answer given as it answered the question actually posed (rather than what I was meaning to ask!  The fault was mine).  Thank you all for your assistance.